# Open eclipse 3.x view in eclipse 4.x using Handlers

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am migrating my 3.x eclipse RCP application to eclipse 4.x, I have imported 3.x Views in application model and now i want to invoke the view from command, So i have created handler in 4.x and in execute method written below code:

```
@Execute
    public void execute(EPartService partService)
    {
      MPart mpart = partService.showPart("com.sample.application.part.other", PartState.ACTIVATE);
    }
```

But this code is not working for 3.x views so please let me know how can i invoke 3.x views in eclipse 4 using handlers?

Comment: Do you mean you are using a pure e4 application which does not have the 3.x compatibility code?

Comment: This is pure e4 application, and i am importing 3.x components in application model

Comment: What does 'import 3.x component' mean? Have you converted it from a IViewPart? Anything that uses stuff from 'org.eclipse.ui.xxx' is not going to work.

Comment: Oh, so it means if i am defining application as "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application", i can not use 3.x views/components in E4? I was assuming that if i will import views in application model using "Import 3.x views" I will be able to use it in pure E4 application. So now i have to use compatibility layer if i want to use 3.x views and 4.x views in the application. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with 'Import 3x View' and there seems to be very little documentation for it. Testing it here it doesn't seem to do very much apart from create a minimal part descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 3.x views are imported as **Shared Elements** in the `Application.e4xmi`, I don't think you'll have a problem with the solution you've posted. The legacy views should be considered as parts.

<strike>You may also want to try converting some of the old views to e4, because the process is quite fast.</strike>

Ultimately, have you tried the old way of opening views?

```
@Execute
public void execute(final EPartService partService) throws PartInitException
{
    final IWorkbenchWindow activeww = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage activePage = activeww.getActivePage();

    activePage.showView("com.sample.application.part.other");
}
```

or even a combination of 3.x/e4

```
@Execute
public void execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws PartInitException
{
    final IWorkbenchWindow activeww = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
    final IWorkbenchPage activePage = activeww.getActivePage();

    activePage.showView("com.sample.application.part.other");
}
```

Comment: None of the old 3.x stuff exists if this is a pure e4 application

Comment: @greg-449 Then I think the first paragraph of my answer should suffice.

Comment: I have tried this, but modelservice returns null for the 3.x view id, Views created in 4.x are working fine with the above code. Do i need to do additional settings apart from importing them in shared elements?

Comment: @Gaurav Is the view's ID the same one as the Shared Element's ID?

Comment: @GGrec, yes the Views ID's are same in plugin.xml as well in shared elements

Answer (score 0):

I have to use compat layer to use 3.x views and will not support in pure 4.x application, after introducing the compat layer above code is working fine now. Thanks